# Multiple warnings after changing min version from build 10240 to Fall Creators Update in Visual Studio UWP Project

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, nuget-package

I need to change the min version as I must implement SQL framework.

Unfortunately, after changing min version to Fall Creators Update I get multiple reference errors, all talking about dll's missing like this:

> The referenced component '(...)Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\netstandard.library\2.0.2\build\netstandard2.0\ref\System.Drawing.dll' could not be found

I get 116 warnings in total. I can still build and launch app, however it makes me wonder whats wrong.

EDIT:

OK. I am pretty much sure whats giving these warnings.
I recreated app by creating new solution and project and moving all code from the previous version.

Everything went smooth until I installed this:

> Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls

And the warnings appeared again.

The app works anyway, and the controls from the package I use work well too. 
But whats wrong with the package? Is it not compatible with fall creators update?

Comment: Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues).

Comment: I found you have got a solution here https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2087, it would benefit for more developers if you can post an answer here.